# Using \dotsm in multiplications along with \cdot

Tags: amsmath, typography

I am aware that by AMS it is recommended to use `\dotsm` in cases like these: `$A_1 A_2 \dotsm A_n$`, `$A_1 A_2 \dotsm$`. Is there any recommendation for its usage along with `\cdot`, i.e. whether `$\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac21 \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac43 \cdot \frac45 \dotsm$` or `$\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac21 \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac43 \cdot \frac45 \cdot \dotsm$` should be used? Other example: `$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dotsm \cdot n$` or `$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \dotsm n$`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMS Style Guide (http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf)
answers this in section 13.5, page 103:

[image: excerpt from AMS style guide]

For input, I would use an explicit `\ldots` here.

As pointed out in a comment by @ivankoken, the `amsmath` user's guide (section 4.3) says

> For most situations, the undifferentiated `\dots` can be used, and
> `amsmath` will output the most suitable form based on the immediate
> context; if an inappropriate form results, it can be corrected after
> examining the output.

This situation -- between a `\cdot` pair -- is such a situation.

Comment: In general, one can go with `\dots` only and exceptionally intervene with `\ldots` in the very occasions? ("For most situations, the undifferentiated \dots can be used, and amsmath will output the most suitable form based on the immediate context; if an inappropriate form results, it can be corrected after examining the output.")